# I keep getting this error message when I try to run the code chunk, Error in is.data.frame(.data) : argument ".data" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, label

Trying to run this code chunk and keep getting the error message

```
trip_data_v2 %>% 
  mutate(weekday = wday(started_at, label = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(member_casual, weekday) %>% 
  summarise(number_of_rides = n())
```

I was trying to visualize the number of rides by rider type
I tried to add '...' as a default argument but that didn't seem to work

Comment: Can you show `dput(head(trip_data_v2))`

Comment: It's hard to tell without reproducible example as akrun has pointed out. But maybe try ```summarise(number_of_rides = n(), groups=TRUE)```, but that's just a guess.